# How to debug the Stored procedure in SQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [SQW].[usp_AddSqaeCapacityAssignHrsData_CMS]
      @ActionType varchar(10)='create',
      @UserPrincipalName varchar(500) = NULL,
      @Id INT = NULL,
      @DataFor VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
      @AreaName varchar(50) = NULL,
      @Region varchar(100) = NULL,
      @CapacityHrs INT = NULL,
      @NoofFolderCapacity INT = NULL,
      @PerFolderCapacityHrs INT = NULL,
      @CompetenciesParams [SQW].[udt_CompetencyList_CMS] READONLY 
AS
BEGIN
    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN T1;
       
    
       IF @DataFor = 'AssignmentHrs'
         BEGIN
              
             MERGE SQW.DimSQAECapacity AS t  
                   USING (  
                          SELECT * FROM @**CompetenciesParams** 
                          ) AS s ON t.Region = @Region AND t.Competency = s.Competency
                WHEN MATCHED THEN  
                       UPDATE SET  
                        t.PerFolderCapacityHrs = @PerFolderCapacityHrs,t.IsActive=1, t.ModifiedDate = GETUTCDATE(), ModifiedBy = @UserPrincipalName
                WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
                    INSERT (  
                            Area,Region,Competency,CapacityHrs,NoofFolderCapacity,PerFolderCapacityHrs,CreatedDate,CreatedBy,ModifiedDate,ModifiedBy
                            )  
                    VALUES (  
                            @AreaName,@Region,s.Competency,NULL,@NoofFolderCapacity,@PerFolderCapacityHrs,GETUTCDATE(),@UserPrincipalName,GETUTCDATE(),@UserPrincipalName
                           );
            END
```

I wanted to know what will be the value passed to @CompetenciesParams in SELECT * FROM @CompetenciesParams as it is passing as a user defined type .

[Stored Procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJncZ.png)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Different products have different possibilities.

Comment: In SQL-Server you would use the profiler tool to capture the stored procedure call and the value of all its parameters.

Comment: Use XEvents trace https://www.scarydba.com/2018/09/24/extended-events-and-stored-procedure-parameter-values/